# Able to ping sites using Ubuntu 20.04 but not access via 'atp-get' or browser

Tags: networking, updates, 20.04

I performed a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop about 1 month ago, applied all of the updates, installed Xen, configured a network bridge, and as far as I could tell everything was working fine. Yesterday I logged back in where it said several updates are available. When running `sudo apt-get update` it sits here for ~1 minute:

0% [Connecting to kazooie.canonical.com (91.189.91.39)]

and then spits out:

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not connect to kazooie.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to banjo.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
...
```

Opening sites in Firefox timeout as well. However, pinging the update and browse-able sites works just fine.

Originally `apt-get update` looked to be trying via IPv6 which I disabled by adding `ipv6.disable=1` to the grub command line but also no luck. I also disabled the network bridge in an attempt to restore my networking back to normal.

And I'm no longer booting into Xen.

Also, another Ubuntu 20.04 machine on the same network is able to update via `apt-get` and access sites in the browser- no problems.

I can't seem to find any other postings of anyone having the same problem. People have mentioned the issues with IPv6 which as stated above is disabled. It's not clear what else to try. Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the mirrors you update from? That'd be my first step.

Comment: I tried both for the US and 'Main' but the same problem. Also note I can't browse any websites as these time out too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ultimately this turned out to be a router issue. Doh. Swapped routers and no more problem.